# the runcommand property is not defined on ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

In `Visual Studio 2017`, I got an error in all projects that are related with `ASP.NET Core 2` .
That says:

> unable to run your project. the runcommand property is not defined

Even I uninstalled the VS and again installed it but I have still this problem.
I tested default project template for VS but those do not execute right, too.
Please help me.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Views\Product\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

netcoreapp2.0
Try changing to:
netstandard2.0

Comment: This answer works for me (on Visual Studio 2019 Preview)! Thank you.